# Scope variable is changing unexpected manner Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner in AngularJS. Recently tried out below code.

**HTML Tag:**

```
 <div ng-app="myApp">
  <input type="text" ng-model="message" />
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  <div ng-controller="ctrlOne">
    <input type="text" ng-model="message" />
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ctrlTwo">
    <input type="text" ng-model="message" />
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS Script:**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("ctrlOne", function($scope) {
console.dir($scope);

});
app.controller("ctrlTwo", function($scope) {
console.dir($scope);

});
```

If you type in the text area. Each output print is unique. Even though I have used common variable to the $scope element.

Can any one please explain,
1. what is happening internally?
2. How angular is handling this scope?
If you can help with step wise advice explaining, so that it is easy for beginner like us to understand.

Your time spent on this highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Please find JSFIDDLE Link Below:
[Code Snippet example on $scope](https://jsfiddle.net/nareshjavastudy/31nmq3tt/1/)

Please check the console. Its is showing undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you have used a common variable, but both of them are under the scope of different controller.

One is under the scope of controller `ctrlone` and other is under the scope of controller `ctrltwo`.

When you create a controller, angular creates a `separate scope` pertaining to that `controller` alone. So even if the names of variables are same but if they are defined on two different scope, they will have unique values.

However, if you want to have a variable with same value in both controller, then you will have to define that variable on `$rootScope` because `$rootScope` is created once per app.

Inside your controller, you can retrieve the value like this:

```
console.log($scope.message);
```

This will give you the value of message as you typed in the input box.

Comment: That was a quick response. I agree with you. But I have also declared a model variable which does not come under any of the controller. what about the scope of this variable that is declared outside controller. To which scope does that bind.

If I want to intialise or retrive value from it , How can I. can you pls modify my fiddle to explain it.

Comment: @NareshRaj it belongs to `$rootScope`

Comment: So every time I create a controller, a new scope is created?

Is there any way to find out and identify Parent scope or child scope through some printing or through console property.

Comment: You can print the $rootScope, the same way you are doing child scope.

Comment: console.dir($scope), I believe I cant print it out side controller ?

Comment: You have to print it inside controller, pass $rootScope as one more dependency and then console it

Comment: You are helping me often with an solution. Thanks, As advised passed $rootScope and I am able to get the value,

Comment: Can you pls click this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nareshjavastudy/31nmq3tt/1/)

If you happen to check the console. It is printing undefined